# What are the relational and absolute quantities in classical mechanics?

Tags: metaphysics, physics

So it seems to a lot classical mechanics involves identifying fundamental quantities (like velocity) but the meaningful questions are absolute quantities like relative velocity.

I've been trying to classify quantities on this basis and it isn't as straight forward. For example, I think potential energy is [relational quantity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/715232/minimum-energy-required-to-behave-like-a-turning-point?noredirect=1&lq=1) and mass is a absolute quantity (in Newtonian mechanics).

Now I realize I am at risk of reinventing the wheel. Has someone already done this? I'd love to read about this?

Comment: Indeed there's been long debate in philosophy of physics between absolutism/substantivalism and relationism regarding space, time and motion. Mass is generally regarded as absolute uncontroversially, and [shape dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_dynamics) as an alternative to GR was initiated by physicist Barbour based upon quotients of rigid translations, rotations and dilatations of the configuration space and the symmetries of dynamical theories explain the "illusory" spacetime geometry. Also see Pooley 2013, *Substantivalist and Relationalist Approaches to Spacetime*...

Comment: You may be interested in *relational mechanics* (there are various formulations, search). That being said, position vectors as used in classical mechanics are indeed relational

Comment: You want to go to wikipedia and start reading. Here's a few, but there are lots more.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conserved_quantity

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Conifold, the fundamental quantities of *dynamics* depend on the choice of tools used to describe those dynamics. The dynamicist makes that choice on the basis of the details of the problem at hand and the desired formalism in which (s)he wishes to express the answer.

One way to approach this problem is through the use of *state variables* to describe the dynamics. This is popular with engineers who have to write predictive models of dynamical systems. A classic work on the use of state variables is Karnopp & Rosenberg, *System Dynamics: A Unified Approach*.